# Does JS bind grab the state of an obj or keep a reference to the obj?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, node.js, asynchronous

My issue is that an array I've bind'ed to an async function doesn't seem to get updated on subsequent calls of that function even though the bind'ed array is updated inside that function.

In the function below I call **queryForData** several times asynchronously. passing in History which is declared globally.  LOG1 always prints out an empty array and LOG2 always prints out an array retrieved with correct data for that iteration.  However, it doesn't seem to concat with the array retrieved in the other calls.

Please help

```
exports.callQuery = function(req, res) {
  var http = require('http');
  var history = [];

  // loop over all entries in "Stocks" collection
  // and call queryForData
  Stocks.find(function (err, stocks){
    stocks.forEach(function callback(entry){
        queryForData(entry, this.history);
        }.bind({history : history})
    );
  });

  // perform an HTTP request for data and call the callback 
  // function which concats the data arrays together.
  var queryForData = function(stockData, history) {   
    var options = {
      host: 'query.blah.com',
      path: '/blah'+stockData
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
      var str = '';

      //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
      response.on('end', function () {

        var data = JSON.parse(str);
        console.log("LOG1: ", this.stocksHistoryData);
        this.stocksHistoryData = this.stocksHistoryData.concat(data);
        console.log("LOG2: ", this.stocksHistoryData);

        }.bind({stocksHistoryData : history})
      );
    };
    http.request(options, callback).end();
  };
};
```

Comment: I find that code really hard to follow, seems all over the place.

Comment: I added some comments and changed the names of some variables to be more clear.

Comment: adding comments and renaming doesn't help the fact that the code is poorly structured and difficult to follow. You don't describe what you want to achieve, but undoubtedly there's a much simpler and cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Using Node.js: For each document in a mongodb collection, I need to call a REST api to get an obj array response.   I then need one  array returned composed of the results of all those arrays retrieved.

Comment: Though this is outside my original issue, I would be very grateful if you can point out how I can better structure this piece of code.  I'm always looking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a *new* array. So, you're overwriting the reference to the array with a new array that's never reachable outside that function's scope. It happens here:

```
this.stocksHistoryData = this.stocksHistoryData.concat(data);
```

Try replacing the above line with:

```
data.forEach(function(item){
    this.stocksHistoryData.push(item);
}, this);
```

That way you always build up the state of the existing array.

Comment: This is exactly it. As soon as I pushed onto the existing array, this worked perfectly. I guess I thought the outside scope still had a reference to the array that's newly created in this function.  Now I know it just doesn't work that way.   Thank you.

Comment: instead of data.forEach(...) you can use this.stocksHistoryData.push.apply(this.stocksHistoryData, data);

Comment: Oh that works even better!  Didn't know that option existed!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you debug your code, but I can answer the question you pose. In JavaScript, objects are always passed "by reference" rather than "by value." So, in the terms of your question, JS bind keeps a reference to obj.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that your `queryForData` function never even uses `this` so it is irrelevant whether or not you bind anything to the function or not. Also if you are going to use `this.history` it would be inside the `queryForData` function body, not arguments that are being passed to it. I believe this code should be changed:

```
// loop over all entries in "Stocks" collection
// and call queryForData
Stocks.find(function (err, stocks){
  stocks.forEach(function callback(entry){
      queryForData(entry, this.history);
      }.bind({history : history})
  );
});
```

to this:

```
// loop over all entries in "Stocks" collection
// and call queryForData
Stocks.find(function (err, stocks){
  stocks.forEach(function callback(entry){
      queryForData(entry, history);
      }.bind()
  );
});
```

This should work fine as objects (arrays are objects) are always passed-by-reference in JavaScript. That way every invocation of `queryForData` will reference the same `history` object that is passed as an argument.